# Unable to uninstall Elasticsearch from CentOS 8 Stream server

Tags: dnf, elasticsearch, module

I'm running CentOS 8 Stream and it has elasticsearch 7.10 installed. When I try to remove this I get the following error

```
# dnf remove elasticsearch-7.10.0-1.x86_64
Modular dependency problems:

 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-IO-Socket-SSL:2.066:8040020200924212038:1aedcbfe.x86_64
 Problem 2: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-libwww-perl:6.34:8040020211102170116:bf75fe78.x86_64
All matches were filtered out by exclude filtering for argument: elasticsearch-7.10.0-1.x86_64
No packages marked for removal.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I'm unsure how to get around this problem. Can someone help?